# How to break correctlly in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question about break the input, because my code is typing two times "-1" to stop the input, actually I want to type "-1" single time to stop the input and then to show the array output.

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewTMA {
    public static float[][] clone(float[][] a) throws Exception {
        float b[][] = new float[a.length][a[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("enter row size");
        int row =  Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter column size");
        int column = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println ("Type float numbers two-dimensional array of similar type and size with line break, end by -1:");
        float[][] a = new float[row][column];

        for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                if ("-1".equals(line)) {
                    break;
                }
                a[i][j]=Float.parseFloat(line);
            }
         }

        System.out.println("\n The result is:");

        try {
            float b[][] = clone(a);

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(b[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my output:

```
   run:
 enter row size
 3
 enter column size
 2
 Type float numbers two-dimensional array of similar type and size with line breaks. end by -1:
 1.4
 2.4
 -1
 -1

 The result is:
 1.4 2.4 
 0.0 0.0 
 0.0 0.0 
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Actually I just want to type  "-1"  a single time to stop the input,but I don't know why the output is showing "-1" twice to stop it. Hope someone can help me find which part I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: you code is not properly indented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` breaks out of the inner-most loop, so the outer loop iterates again and hits the input read again.

To break out of the *outer* loop, use a *label*:

```
outerLoop: // label the outer for loop
for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if ("-1".equals(line)) {
            break outerLoop; // break from the outer for loop
    }
    ...
 }
```

You can use any java allowable name for the label (I just called it “outerLoop” for clarity)

Comment: Thanks your answer. Can you put your answer to insert my coding to modify?

Comment: Just add a label to the outer loop and refer to it in the `break`.

Comment: I've added but something error. So hope you can help me to add your answer into my coding to easy I do the checking.

Comment: Thanks. I have successed to edit. Your method is right!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be putting a flag as an indication if the argument is met:

```
 for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
    /* this is the flag */
    boolean isInputNegative = false;
    for (int j=0; j<column; j++){
       String line = sc.nextLine();
       if ("-1".equals(line)){
           isInputNegative = true;
           break;
       }
       a[i][j]=Float.parseFloat(line);
   }
   /* here is the checking part */
   if (isInputNegative) {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are always written in camelCase.

Comment: @MC Emperor, yeah I forget. I used to code  in o ther language. Thanks mate.